# asyncio create_task() to be first in queue?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

As I understand when I call `create_task()` it will put at the end of the event loop queue.

My use case is the following, I have some tasks made of the same coroutine. I want to cancel all tasks on some failed condition. This is the pattern:

```
async def coro(params):
   # long running task...
   if failed_condition:
        await cancel_all()  # should cancel all tasks made of coro

async def cancel_all():
   for task in tasks:
        task.cancel()
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)  # wait for cancel completion
    print("All tasks cancelled")

tasks = []
async def main():

    tasks = [loop.create_task(coro(params)) for x in range(5)]
    asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

The problem is that since `cancel_all()` itself is awaited by one task, it is cancelled by itself.

How can I solve this? 
I could use `loop.create_task(cancel_all())` instead, but I want the cancel_all() to run soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

`cancel_all()` could exclude the current task:

```
async def cancel_all():
    to_cancel = set(tasks)
    to_cancel.discard(asyncio.current_task())
    for task in to_cancel:
        task.cancel()
    await asyncio.gather(*to_cancel)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [asyncio.wait](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait) with `FIRST_EXCEPTION` parameter.

```py
import asyncio
import random

class UnexpectedCondition(Exception):
    pass

async def coro(condition):
    # long running task...
    await asyncio.sleep(random.random()*10)
    if condition:
        raise UnexpectedCondition("Failed")
    return "Result"

async def main(f):
    tasks = [coro(f(x)) for x in range(5)]
    done, pending = await asyncio.wait(tasks, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_EXCEPTION)

    for p in pending:
        # unfinished tasks will be cancelled
        print("Cancel")
        p.cancel()

    for d in done:
        try:
            # get result from finished tasks
            print(d.result())
        except UnexpectedCondition as e:
            # handle tasks with unexpected conditions
            print(e)

asyncio.run(main(lambda x: x%2 == 0))
```